# set int of a struct from a memory buffer

Tags: c, struct, pointer-arithmetic

I have more of a cosmetic question:

I have a memory stream (void *) which i use in the sample as "cur_ptr".
Now i want to read the first bytes into a int ("version") of a struct ("a_struct").
My code that works:

```
int *version;
version = cur_ptr;
a_struct->version = *version;
```

How can i write it without the helping pointer *version?

That one won't work:

```
a_struct->version = (int)*cur_ptr;
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cast cur_ptr to int* then get it's value ;)

```
*((int*)cur_ptr);
```